# Finding the rest of the string with newlines Python

Tags: python, regex, string, match, newline

I have a string msg like this

```
msg = "abc 123 \n  456"
```

I want to do something like this

```
m = re.match('abc (.*)',msg)
```

and have m.groups return "123 \n  456"

but currently it only returns "123 "

How would i capture the rest of the string rather than just until the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

Use the `s` ( *dotall* ) modifier forcing the dot to match all characters, including line breaks.

```
>>> import re
>>> msg = "abc 123 \n  456"
>>> m = re.match(r'(?s)abc (.*)', msg)
>>> m.group(1)
'123 \n  456'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag, otherwise the `.` regular expression atom will not match newlines.

> `re.DOTALL:` Make the `'.'` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `'.'` will match anything *except* a newline.

So this should do what you want:

```
m = re.match('abc (.*)', msg, re.DOTALL)
```